# On page change, getting info from database table using Ajax and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

As I wrote in other posts I don't have satisfying knowledge in Ajax and jQuery so please I will need little help here..I have already built pagination for some articles(each page shows 2 articles - 5 pages for now) but I would like to get article info from a database table.I will need Ajax for doing that..Any ideas?

Code for articles:

```
<div id="slider">
    <div id="slider-wrapper">
    <div id="slide">
    <div class="row top-buffer">
             <div class="col-md-6">
             <img class="img-rounded" src="img/strawberry-wallpaper.jpg" alt="MyImage" width="550px" height="240px">
               </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
         <h3>Title</h3>
                            <p class="well">Some Title...<p>

                                    <div class="row top-buffer">

                                        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
                                        <img src="img/link_icon.png" class="img-rounded" width="20px" height="20px"/>
                                        <a href="#">Link</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">

                               <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="btn">Read More</button>



                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
             .
             .
             .
 </div>
<div id="slider-nav">
    <a href="#" data-slide="0">1</a>
    <a href="#" data-slide="1">2</a>
    <a href="#" data-slide="2">3</a>
    <a href="#" data-slide="3">4</a>
    <a href="#" data-slide="4">5</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using php? .net? to serve the contents back to your client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did similar pagination and see its really helps you

```
<?php if (isset($patientBills['rows']) && !empty($patientBills['rows'])) { ?>

    <table class="ui cell striped table">
        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th rowspan="2">Bill No</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Bill Date & Time</th>
            </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tbody>
                <?php  $rowindex =1;      foreach ($patientBills['rows'] as $bill) {
      ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a title="View Bill" href="<?php echo BILLING_PATH .  'patient/' . $bill['patient_id'] . '/' . $rowindex * $page; ?>">
                                <?php echo $bill['bill_no']; ?>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php $date=date_create($bill['paid_date']); echo date_format($date, DATE_FORMAT); ?>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    <?php } ?>

            </tbody>
        </tbody>
<?php if ($patientBills['totalpages'] > 1) { ?>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="9">
                    <div class="ui floated right border pagination menu ">
                        <a id="previousbtn" name="pageNavbtn" class="<?php echo $patientBills[ 'page']==1 ? 'disabled': ''; ?> item">
                            <i class="left arrow icon"></i> Previous </a>
                        <?php 
                            $startPage = 1;
                            $loop = 0;
                            if ($patientBills['page'] > NO_OF_PAGES) {
                                $startPage = $patientBills['page'] - NO_OF_PAGES + 2;
                            }
                            for ($pag = $startPage; $pag <= $patientBills["totalpages"]; $pag++) { $loop ++?>
                            <a href="#" class="<?php  echo $patientBills['page']== $pag ? 'disabled': ''; ?> item" name="patientPageLink" id="<?php echo $pag; ?>">
                                <?php echo $pag; ?>
                            </a>
                            <?php $loop == NO_OF_PAGES ? $pag = $patientBills["totalpages"] + 1:''; ?>
                                <?php } 
                    if ($patientBills["totalpages"] > NO_OF_PAGES) { ?>
                                    <a id="nextPagebtn" name="pageNavbtn" class="<?php  echo $patientBills['page'] == $patientBills['totalpages'] ? 'disabled':''; ?> item">Next&nbsp;
                        <i class="icon right arrow"></i></a>
                                    <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
<?php  } ?>
    </table>
    <?php  } else {?>
No bills created for this patient.
<?php  } ?>

        <script>



            $('a[name=pageNavbtn], a[name=patientPageLink]').click(function () {
                var currentPage = <?php echo $patientBills['page']; ?>;
                var totalpages = <?php echo $patientBills['totalpages']; ?>;
                if (this.id == 'previousbtn') {
                    if (currentPage > 1) {
                        currentPage -= 1;
                    }
                } else if (this.id == 'nextPagebtn') {
                    if (currentPage < totalpages) {
                        currentPage += 1;
                    }
                } else {
                    currentPage = this.id;
                }
                var postData = {
                    page: currentPage
                    , patientId: <?php echo $patientId;?>
                };
                var Url = "<?php echo PATIENT_PATH . GET_BILL_LIST_BY_PAGENO; ?>";
                triggerAjaxPost(Url, postData, function (resdata) {
                    $('#billlistcontainer').html(resdata);
                });
            });

        </script>
```

//resdata will be constructed in html format

```
// DB Query
$count_query   = "
                SELECT
                     COUNT(*) as count
                FROM
                    patient_billing 
                    WHERE
                    patientid  = "  . $patientid;

        $result_count = mysqli_query($this->_connection, $count_query); 
           $rowcount = mysqli_fetch_array($result_count);
            $count = $rowcount['count']; 
            $limit  = $this->_limit;
            $page = $this->_page;
            $sidx = $this->_sidx;
            $sort = $this->_sort;
    $sortBy = $this->_sidx;
    if (empty($sort)){
        $sort =  'desc';
    }
    if (empty($limit)){
        $limit =  1;
    }
    if (empty($page)){
        $page =  1;
    }
        if (empty($sortBy)){
        $sortBy =  '  bill_no ';
    }

        if($count > 0 && $limit > 0) { 
          $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit); 
        } else { 
          $total_pages = 0; 
        } 
        if ($page > $total_pages) $page=$total_pages;

        $start = $limit * $page - $limit;

        if($start <0) $start = 0;

        $query     = "
                     SELECT
                     *
                FROM
                    patient_billing 
                    WHERE
                    patientid  = "  . $patientid . " " .
            "  ORDER BY " . $sortBy .  " " . $sort
            . " LIMIT " . $start .",". $limit;
    $result   = mysqli_query($this->_connection, $query) or die("Couldn't execute query: " . mysqli_error($this->_connection));

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {                
              $responce[] = $row;
            }
        }

    $patientBills= array("totalpages"=>$total_pages, "page"=>$page, "records"=>$count, "rows"=>$responce);
```

Comment: I need to understand it first.It is a little bit tricky for me.No such experience.Your answer will be helpful!

Comment: Ok thanks.. :-) please comment, if you stuck up anywhere.

Comment: I will do that..Thanks again!

Comment: I checked your code.I think I understand it..I can't figure it out how you get info fro database.There must be a `select` query above your code?

Comment: Edited and added the query

Comment: I added the `select` query above and I changed this `<?php if (isset($stmt_select['rows']) && !empty($stmt_select['rows'])) { ?>`.I have named the file as `ajax.php` but when I run it, it brings nothing to page..

Comment: Can you check the value print_r($stmt_select);

Comment: That is the result `PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT * FROM `articles`; ) `

Comment: $stmt_select is select query, should not pass the query.

Comment: Pass the result set of the query

Comment: Mark as answered if its really helpful